# Identify parent of hierarchical data in a dataframe given ordered index and depth only

Tags: python, pandas

Before I begin, I can hack something together to do this on a small scale, but my goal is to apply this to 200k+ row dataset, so efficiency is priority and I lack more...  nuanced techniques. :-)

So, I have an *ordered* data set that represents data from a very complex hierarchical structure.  I only have a unique ID, the tree depth, and the fact that it is in order.  For example:

```
a
    b
        c
            d
            e
        f
        g
            h
i
    j
       k
    l
```

Which is stored as:

```
     ID   depth
0    a    0
1    b    1
2    c    2
3    d    3
4    e    3
5    f    2
6    g    2
7    h    3
8    i    0
9    j    1
10   k    2
11   l    1
```

Here's a line that should generate my example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ "ID":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"], 
                              "depth":[0,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,0,1,2,1] })
```

What I want is to return either the index of each elements' nearest parent node or the parents' unique ID (they'll both work since they're both unique). Something like:

```
     ID   depth parent p.idx
0    a    0
1    b    1     a      0
2    c    2     b      1
3    d    3     c      2
4    e    3     c      2
5    f    2     b      1
6    g    2     b      1
7    h    3     g      6
8    i    0
9    j    1     i      8
10   k    2     j      9
11   l    1     i      8
```

My initial sloppy solution involved adding a column that was `index-1`, then self matching the data set with `idx-1` (left) and `idx` (right), then identifying the maximum parent `idx` less than the child index... it didn't scale up well.

Comment: I believe the parent of `l` (last row) should be `8` not `10`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of routes to performing this task I've put together that *work* but aren't very efficient.

The first uses simple loops and includes a `break` to exit when the first match is identified.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ "ID":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"], "depth":[0,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,0,1,2,1] })
df["parent"] = ""

# loop over entire dataframe
for i1 in range(len(df.depth)):

    # loop back up from current row to top
    for i2 in range(i1):

        # identify row where the depth is 1 less
        if df.depth[i1] -1 == df.depth[i1-i2-1]:

            # Set parent value and exit loop
            df.parent[i1] = df.ID[i1-i2-1]
            break

df.head(15)
```

This second merges the dataframe with itself and then uses a groupby to identify the maximum parent row less than each original row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ "ID":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"], "depth":[0,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,0,1,2,1] })

#  Columns for comparision and merging
df["parent_depth"] = df.depth-1
df["row"]=df.index

# Merge to return ALL elements matching the parent depth of each row
df = df.merge(df[["ID","depth","row"]], left_on="parent_depth",right_on="depth",how="left",suffixes=('','_y'))

# Identify the maximum parent row less than the original row
g1 = df[ (df.row_y < df.row) | (df.row_y.isnull())].groupby("ID").max()
g1.reset_index(inplace=True)

#clean up
g1.drop(["parent_depth","row","depth_y","row_y"],axis=1,inplace=True)
g1.rename({"ID_y":"parent"},inplace=True)

g1.head(15)
```

I'm confident those with more experience can provide more elegant solutions, but since I got *something* working, I wanted to provide my "solution".  Thanks!